# Proving $S_{4} = S_{1} \cap S_{2}$. Where $S_{j} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: F_{j}(x,y) = 0\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, elementary-set-theory

Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be $C^1$ functions defined on some open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Further define $F_{4} = F_{1}^{2} + F_{2}^{2}$. For $j = 1,\cdots,4$, let $S_{j} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: F_{j}(x,y) = 0\}$

Prove $S_{4} = S_{1} \cap S_{2}$.

Attempt:

$$\Rightarrow \text{Let}\  (a,b) \in S_{4} \\ \Rightarrow\ F_{4}(a,b) = 0 \\
\Rightarrow 0 = F_{1}^{2} + F_{2}^{2} \\ \Rightarrow F_{1}^{2} = -F_{2}^{2} $$

This is where I'm stuck, how can I relate this to what I WANT which would be to show $(a,b) \in S_{1} \cap S_{2}$?

Comment: A fundamental property of real numbers: If $a^2+b^2=0$, then $a=b=0$.

Comment: You know what, I actually knew that, but I didn't remember that. These sorts of general "facts" I tend to not remember to well, what do you do to decide between what to keep at the top of your mind vs what not to?